# Read text file from online server part by part

Tags: linux, bash

There is a 20GB file online, I want to get it part by part using bash/linux commands with the ability to read each part alone. Is this possible?

Comment: The file is too large to be downloaded and I only need a specific content inside it (which is at the beginning of the file) so I thought I would download 500MB or so from the file instead of having to download all of it.

Comment: Okay, seems like browsers can help a lot. I just changed the content-type of the response to `text/plain` instead of `application/octet-stream` (it's a .log file) and the browser did it for me.